# Set group field of a contact as required

Tags: groups

I need that when saving contact validate the entry of the group field.
How can I do it?

Comment: What sort of validation do you require?  What CMS are you using? If Drupal you may be able to do it using https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation and webform_civicrm

Comment: You refer to both 'set' and 'validate' which are different.  Can you expand a bit on what you are wanting to do?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write small [extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/) and then implement [hook_civicrm_validateForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) to validate group field and then throw error. Example

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_validateForm().
 *
 * @param string $formName
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $files
 * @param CRM_Core_Form $form
 * @param array $errors
 */
function xxxx_civicrm_validateForm($formName, &$fields, &$files, &$form, &$errors) {
  if ('CRM_Contact_Form_Contact' == $formName) {
    if (!empty($fields['group']) && !in_array(10, $fields['group'])) {
      $errors['group'] = ts('Group field contains invalid option.');
    }
  }
}
```

HTH

Pradeep